# Дублирование кода в Meta-Класс Django

Tags: python, django

Создал несколько абстрактных классов модели AbstractBaseContent и AbstractContent. В AbstractBaseContent создал Meta-класс с ordering и unique_together, но в AbstractContent приходится снова дублировать строки. Как это исправить?

```
class BaseContent:
   Fields
   ...

    class Meta:
       abstract = True
       ordering = ['-created']
       unique_together = ['title', 'description', 'author']


class Post(BaseContent):
   Fields
   ...

   class Meta:
      ordering = ['-created']
      unique_together = ['title', 'description', 'author']



class CV(BaseContent):
   Fields
   ...

   class Meta:
      ordering = ['-created']
      unique_together = ['title', 'description', 'author']
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Дух сообщества
Добавил

Comment: `class Meta(BaseContent.Meta): ...` ???

Comment: @ZaArs а abstract тоже перейдёт class Meta(BaseContent.Meta)?

Comment: По идее да, не проверял, но скорее 99% да. Но что мешает вынести основные поля мета класса в отдельный класс? и наследовать от него? Я просто показал, как может работать.

Comment: А вообще проще проверить, может все уже работает как надо. Я с подобным не сталкивался, и не вкурсе как работает Django в этом случае, может она учитывает мета классы родительских классов